# Segfault when using std::string.c_str() as an argument for another method

Tags: c++, string, stl, stat

Can anyone tell me why using returned const char* from c_str() as an argument in stat(const char*, stat*) causes the program to segfault?  I think I've narrowed down my segfault to being caused by that line, but I'm not sure what to use instead.  I tried copying the string into a character array using strcpy(), but that just caused the program to segfault as the method was returning, which isn't much better.

```
DIR * dir_p;
struct dirent *dir_entry_p;
list<string> files;
dir_p = opendir(".");
//push all file names to a list
while((dir_entry_p = readdir(dir_p))!=NULL){
    string name = dir_entry_p->d_name;
    files.push_front(name);
}
closedir(dir_p);
files.sort();
//count total blocks
//iterate through list
map<string,struct  stat*> fileStats;
struct stat * entry;
for(list<string>::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); it++){
    stat(it->c_str(),entry);
    fileStats[*it]=entry;
    cout<<entry->st_blocks<<" "<<*it<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `g++ -Wall -g`). Improve code till no warnings are given. Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and your **debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: @H2CO3, I'm open to suggestions on how to avoid an "unformatted, unreadable mess".  Simply saying that it's so is not something I can take into account when writing code later on.  As it is, your comment is simply unhelpful and inflammatory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's the `c_str()` making troubles here, but how you're using `struct stat`.
You should create a `struct stat` instance and pass it's address:

```
// ...

//iterate through list
map<string,struct  stat> fileStats;
for(list<string>::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); it++){
    struct stat entry;
    stat(it->c_str(),&entry);
    fileStats[*it]=entry;
    cout<<entry.st_blocks<<" "<<*it<<endl;
}
```

What you're doing is letting `stat()` write to the address coming from an uninitialized pointer (which will most likely end up in a segfault).

Note that you'll also need to change the map type to get this working.

Comment: @Dazedy Take care how you're initializing the pointer (memory leaks, etc.). The code I've posted should work fine, and doesn't add any additional overhead.